# Ambiguous class resolution warning during composer update

Tags: laravel-5, migration, composer-php

During composer update i'm facing ambiguous class resolution warning. Screenshot given below and i was trying https://github.com/Doptor/Doptor this laravel cms. [image]

Comment: What is the problem? It was already reported: https://github.com/Doptor/Doptor/issues/187 - after all it's warning, but if you don't like it you can exclude duplicated classes: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#exclude-files-from-classmaps

Comment: Two files with same classnames

Answer (score 1):

Two files with same class names.Please remove any one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the vendor directory and running composer install got rid of the errors for me.